# C++ extract type of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

Let's suppose that I have

```
typedef T* PtrType;
```

Is there a way to extract from `PtrType` the type `T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::remove_pointer<PtrType>::type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer)

If `T` is a template parameter, you'll have to use:

`typename std::remove_pointer<PtrType>::type`

Comment: And for convenience: `template <typename T> using remove_pointer_t = typename std::remove_pointer<PtrType>::type;`

Comment: You mean `template <typename T> using remove_pointer_t=typename std::remove_pointer<PtrType>::type;`?

Comment: In fact I mean `template <typename T> using remove_pointer_t = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type;` with other typo (`T`/`PtrType`) fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Been banging my head against the wall all day trying to convince `decltype(array[0])` to not return lvalue reference types. Works great with `std::remove_pointer<decltype(array)>::type`. Finally... relief.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can use [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
std::remove_pointer<PtrType>::type
```

Without C++11, you can trivially implement this yourself:

```
template <class T>
struct remove_pointer;

template <class U>
struct remove_pointer<U*>
{
  typedef U type;
};
```

The above will remove a pointer from `T` if `T` is indeed a pointer, and result in a compilation error otherwise. If you want to exactly match what `std::remove_pointer` does, you would provide the default case as well:

```
template <class T>
struct remove_pointer
{
  typedef T type;
};

// Partial specialisation for U* same as before
```

Comment: Your answer does not implement `std::remove_pointer`.  `std::remove_pointer` has `typedef T type;` if `T` is not a pointer type.  For a proper possible implementation of `std::remove_pointer`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer).